# Javascript - select value in selector from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to auto select an option in a `<select>` with an array.

**My array**

```
var students = [
    [1, "John Doe"],
    [3, "Mike Tyson"],
    [4, "Vin Diesel"],
];
```

**My Form**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">John Doe</option>
            <option value="2">Myke Tyson</option>
            <option value="3">Vin Diesel</option>
            <option value="4">Michael Jackson</option>
            <option value="5">50 Cent</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">John Doe</option>
            <option value="2">Myke Tyson</option>
            <option value="3">Vin Diesel</option>
            <option value="4">Michael Jackson</option>
            <option value="5">50 Cent</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">John Doe</option>
            <option value="2">Myke Tyson</option>
            <option value="3">Vin Diesel</option>
            <option value="4">Michael Jackson</option>
            <option value="5">50 Cent</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I need to auto select an option for each `<select>` if present in my array:

- John Doe (for first `<select>`)
- Myke Tyson (for second `<select>`)
- Vin Diesel (for third `<select>`)

How can I do this?

Comment: how can you tell which select the value to be selected from?

Comment: Well. This is going to come down to reading the selected option, and with conditional statements or a switch, choosing the appropriate index within your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple loop with [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to filter the `select` element, then `.val()` to set the value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  $('select').eq(i).val(students[i][0]);
}
```

```js
var students = [
  [1, "John Doe"],
  [3, "Mike Tyson"],
  [4, "Vin Diesel"],
];

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  $('select').eq(i).val(students[i][0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">John Doe</option>
            <option value="2">Myke Tyson</option>
            <option value="3">Vin Diesel</option>
            <option value="4">Michael Jackson</option>
            <option value="5">50 Cent</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">John Doe</option>
            <option value="2">Myke Tyson</option>
            <option value="3">Vin Diesel</option>
            <option value="4">Michael Jackson</option>
            <option value="5">50 Cent</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">John Doe</option>
            <option value="2">Myke Tyson</option>
            <option value="3">Vin Diesel</option>
            <option value="4">Michael Jackson</option>
            <option value="5">50 Cent</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```